# How to change drive in IPython under windows

Tags: windows, ipython

How can I change drive letter while in IPython under windows?
For example, !cd W: does **not** make W: the current path, it just changes the path **if** you would change to drive W.
Changing to a dos shell with !cmd and then changing to W: does not have any effect to the IPython shell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the `cd ?` command:

> Note that !cd doesn't work for this purpose because the shell where
>   !command runs is immediately discarded after executing 'command'.

So, just use the `cd`, and make sure to quote path so the colon after the drive letter isn't misinterpreted.

```
cd 'W:'
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a Win 10 machine with Anaconda 2020.11 python installed, out of the box no updates.  ipython 7.19.0.  The *only* way I can cd to somewhere on another drive letter is

> cd d:/

No other permutation works: cd d:, cd d:, cd d:\, cd 'd:', cd 'd:', etc.

So there's an answer but it's quite annoying to figure out.